# How to reload a component with a new list?

Tags: html, angular, ionic3, components

I want to reload my component by clicking a button with a new list. So my problem is that it does not reload the component with the new list after clicking one of the buttons. Can somebody help me with it? Thanks a lot.

This is my HTML-File where i hand over my list.

```
<div class="content_box_left" *ngIf="isloaded==true">
  <component [list]="actualList"></component>
</div>
```

Some code from my Typescript-File:

```
actualList=[];
list1=[1, 2, 3, "dog"];
list2=[3, "cat", "mouse", 47];

button1(){
   console.log("Button 1 pressed");
   this.actualList=this.list1;
}
button2(){
   console.log("Button 2 pressed");
   this.actualList=this.list2;
}
```

Component-HTML-Code:

```
<div>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let list of list">
            <ion-label>{{list}}</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</div>
```

Component-Typescript-Code:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'caiditems',
  templateUrl: 'caiditems.html'
})
export class CaiditemsComponent {

  @Input()
  list = []; 
  constructor() {}    
 }
}
```

Comment: what was the problem

Comment: it does not reload the component after clicking the button. So the list which should be changed isnt changed.

Comment: can you post "component" typescript code?

Comment: added code from component

Comment: The component stuff works fine. If i fill actualList with items it will be displayed by accessing the side. But the refresh with a new list does not work...

Comment: No problem with the binding it is working. Can you post updateList(list) method code? lets see how are you emitting event?

Comment: The updateList(list) function doesnt exist anymore. So it should normally be removed. Updated my post

Comment: from where you are calling button1 and button1 functions? above code works perfectly fine for me

Comment: hmm okay ill set up a stackblizz poject, give me a second

Answer (score 1):

Found out whats the problem. *ngFor does not update after some changes in the array or list happens. Using trackBy was the solution for my problem: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Answer (score -1):

you have error here

```
actualList=[];
list1=[1, 2, 3, dog];
list2=[3, cat, mouse, 47];
```

change to

```
actualList=[];
list1=[1, 2, 3, 'dog'];
list2=[3, 'cat', 'mouse', 47];
```

dog, cat, mouse are string you need single quote. Rest of the code is fine. Take a look at my stackblitz. I used your code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zbvh8k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: nah thats was a bug by changing the elements of my list. i think the problem is that i have an ion-label at my component-html file ?

Comment: do one thing, implement ngOnChanges inside CaiditemsComponent and console.log(this.list) and tell me what it prints when you click button.

Comment: Hm can you explain where and how? Never done this before